# Regex take everything after word and before character in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get regex to work to take everything after "test" and before "@" in an email so "test-12345@example.com would become 12345.

I've got this far to get it to return everything before the "@" symbol. (Working in PHP)

```
!(\d+)@!
```

Comment: *take everything after "test" and before "@"* then output should be `-12345`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you can use capturing groups and use the regex

```
test-(\d+)@
```

and use `$1` or use lookaheads and behinds like `(?<=test-)\d+(?=@)` which will just match `12345`

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=test-)[^@]+
```

You can try this.No need to use groups.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eZ0yP4/28

Answer (score 0):

You want everything between `test` and `@` so don't use `\d`.

```
$myRegexPattern = '#test([^@])*@#Ui';
preg_match ($myRegexPattern, $input, $matches);
$whatYouNeed = $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$input = 'test-12345@example.com';
$regexPattern =  '/^test(.*?)\@/';
preg_match ($regexPattern, $input, $matches);
$whatYouNeed = $matches[1];
var_dump($whatYouNeed);
```